# Creating Two Columns for Author and Date in YAML

Tags: r, yaml, r-markdown

I am using r markdown to create a course outline in which I want to keep the Author and Date in YAML on the left and right side respectively (in a parallel way, not one below another). I write the following code

````
---
title: 
- <br> MGT 460-001 Strategic Management <br>

subtitle:
- <font size="3"> <center> Fall 2019 <br> Rnhe Hall 0018 <br> MW 2:00PM - 3:15PM </center> 
author: 
- Instructor - Louie Joe <br> Office- Rnhe Hall 120 <br> Office Phone - (123) 456 7890 <br> E-mail - lj0123@uni.edu
date: 
- Office Hours - <br> Mon 2:00 – 4:00 <br> Wed  2:00 – 4:00 <br> Tue    2:00 – 5:00
output:
  html_notebook: default
  code_folding: hide
  df_print: paged
  highlight: tango
  theme: united
  geometry: margin= 1in
  fontsize: 12pt
---

<style type="text/css">

h1.title {
  font-size: 38px;
  color: DarkRed;
  text-align: center;
}

h4.date { /* Header 4 - and the author and data headers use this too  */
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  color: DarkBlack;
  text-align: right;
}

h4.author { /* Header 4 - and the author and data headers use this too  */
    font-size: 18px;
  font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  color: DarkBlack;
  text-align: left;
}

body {
text-align: justify} 

</style>
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```
Then I got following output
[![enter image description here][1]
````

Then I got following output
[[image]

I want it this way -

```
Instructor: Louie JOe                             Office Hours -             
Office - Rhne Hall 120                            Mon 2:00 - 4:00
Office Phone - (123) 456 7890                     Tue 2:00 - 4:00
E-mail: lj0123@uni.edu                            Wed 2:00 - 4:00
```

Note that this is for YAML, not the body of the document.

Comment: Please include a complete example of your input.  (You can leave out the content, but we need to be able to run it without an error.)  We need to know what output format are you specifying, which determines the pandoc template, and maybe the LaTeX style.

Comment: @user2554330 I have added the example. Can you help me now?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `float` instead of `text-align` for the author and date CSS.  That is, make these changes in the style section in the body of your document:

```
h4.date { /* Header 4 - and the author and data headers use this too  */
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  color: DarkBlack;
  float: right;
}

h4.author { /* Header 4 - and the author and data headers use this too  */
    font-size: 18px;
  font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  color: DarkBlack;
  float: left;
}
```

When I do that, I see this:

[image: screenshot]